# How to Access All Values of Cursor in MessageBox in foxpro?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have a cursor named `MyCursor` containing a field named `records`. The below code only shows the last record of the cursor. How do I get all the records from cursor to display?

```
Varible=Mycursor.records
MessageBox(Varible)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what data type the 'records' field is but this will work regardless:

```
lcMessage = ""
select mycursor
scan
    lcMessage = lcMessage + transform(records) + chr(13)
endscan
messagebox(lcMessage)
```